# How to pre-concatenate an URL and use it in an onclick?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to put a pre-concatened URL in my onclick in order to open a page with a get parameter, but it actually doesn't work. 
Can someone help me please?

```
$link_prod='"ficheProduit.php'.$prod_disp['ref'].'"';
<button onclick="window.location.href='<?=$link_prod ?>'" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-5 marginbtn">En savoir plus</button>
```

Comment: Please tell us what _doesn't work_ means. Are you getting an error message, wrong URL, etc.

Comment: you have unnecessary quotes

Comment: `$link_prod='ficheProduit.php'.$prod_disp['ref'];
<button onclick="window.location.href=encodeURl('<?php echo $link_prod;?>')" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-5 marginbtn">En savoir plus</button>`

Comment: Do a view source on the page and you will see.

Comment: by "doesn't work", i mean, that the file doesn't recognize the URL as a URL, ans the buttun doesn't send me to the wanted page

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `"` quote from `$link_prod`.

Here's updated code.

```
$link_prod = 'ficheProduit.php' . $prod_disp['ref'];
<button
    onclick="window.location.href='<?=$link_prod ?>'"
    class="btn btn-primary col-lg-5 marginbtn"
>
    En savoir plus
</button>
```

Otherwise, you can also try this.

```
$link_prod = '"ficheProduit.php' . $prod_disp['ref'] . '"';
<button
    onclick="window.location.href=<?=$link_prod ?>"
    class="btn btn-primary col-lg-5 marginbtn"
>
    En savoir plus
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have finally found a solution:

```
$link_prod='ficheProduit.php?ref='.$prod_disp['ref'];
<button onclick=window.location.href="<?php echo $link_prod;?>" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-5 marginbtn">En savoir plus</button>
```

I've added `?ref=`, but it wasn't the main problem.